# Name for the people who hustle you into restaurants

Tags: word-usage, word-request

What do you call those people who hustle you into restaurants, like those in tourist areas that stand in the street with a menu, suggesting you go into their restaurant. (Brussels is a good example.)

Answer (score 5):

For the theater, these are **barkers**. These could be called barkers too.

Google, first hit:

> **barker** bark·er /ˈbärkər/ noun INFORMAL
>
> a person who stands in front of a theater, sideshow, etc., and calls
>   out to passersby to attract customers.

Answer (score 4):

One term for the hustler is a **tout**. The Oxford Dictionaries has [this definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tout)

> **tout**
>   *1.1* A person soliciting custom or business, typically in a direct or persistent manner.

The most relevant usage example comes from the verb form:

> *shop managers would stand in the street touting for business*

This may be a British usage.

There are numerous references to **restaurant touts in Brussels** to be found, such as [this one](https://www.chowhound.com/post/solo-dining-rec-brussels-320934?commentId=1837816). Some others are in guide books which are not so easy to link.

Comment: Evidently, _tout_ as a noun can be an Americanism, too – although it [seems to have a different meaning](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/tout_2). Maybe we don't have a word for it because we don't see the practice much around here.

Comment: @J.R. we say [**tipster**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/tipster) for that, which is also an AmE term.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative may be **promoter**. Generally not used within a restaurant context, but a promoter attempts to attract attention from people and get them to visit their establishment (typically a bar/club/etc)