# A translation for "propper" (promotor) in Dutch to English

Tags: word-request

I'm trying to explain with a metaphor what a recruiter is.

In Dutch a **propper** would be a good fit. A "propper" is a nightclub / disco promoter. Someone who is paid to lure people inside often with false promises an slick talks.
What would be a good single word to convey this exact same profession?
I feel like promotor might not have the same "load" / negative association as it's Dutch counterpart has.

**edit:** They are not the same as hustlers, as hustlers do something illegal and both recruiters and proppers do not (although they show annoying behaviour).

(The [wikipedia page](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propper) exists only in Dutch (no links to other languages))

Comment: Note that in Dutch the verb "proppen" means to cram/stuff things into a container or in this case place, usually beyond capacity. The verb itself conveys that it is not a good/neutral action. I woudn't know the best translation though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name for the people who hustle you into restaurants](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/211834/name-for-the-people-who-hustle-you-into-restaurants)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ***[puller-in](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/puller-in)***

> one that pulls in
>   specifically : *a man who stands in front of a store or place of entertainment and tries sometimes forcibly to get passersby to enter*.

(M-W)

Comment: Thank you, is the word understood by most people without having to look it up?

Comment: In the USA and Britain, fairgrounds, circuses, theatres, etc, used to employ 'barkers'.

Comment: @Thomas I’d say so, especially if used contextually.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey if you make that comment an answer you at least deserve an upvote!